# Log4j2: How to use replace parameter in log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Using log4j2, I want to replace some strings in log message (say replace ***foo*** with ***bar***). In xml configuration, I can use the following configuration and it works.

```
<Appenders>
     <Console name="A1" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] %m%n">
             <replace regex = "foo" replacement="bar"/>
         </PatternLayout>
     </Console>
</Appenders>
```

But insted of using XML, I have to use properties file in my project, so I tried something like

```
appender.A1.type = Console
appender.A1.name = A1
appender.A1.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.A1.layout.pattern = [%d{HH:mm:ss}] %m%n
# Probably BAD code begin
appender.A1.layout.replace.regex = foo
appender.A1.layout.replace.replacement = bar
# Probably BAD code end
```

And I got error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No type attribute provided for component replace
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createComponent(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:334)
...
```

How can I represent ***replace*** in properties file and in log4j2, is it possible to transform everything in xml configuration to properties configuration?
I'm using log4j-api-2.14.0.jar and log4j-core-2.14.0.jar.

Thx in advance!

**EDIT:**
I 've also tried `replace{pattern}{regex}{substitution}` before. And I think this is different from the **replace** parameter.
Say the pattern is

```
appender.A1.layout.pattern = [%d{HH:mm:ss}][%C::%M] %replace{%m}{foo}{bar}%n
```

And I will get

```
[09:28:07][com.foo.MyApp::main] 111 bar 222
```

but what I want to get is

```
[09:28:07][com.bar.MyApp::main] 111 bar 222
```

Using above XML configuration, I can get the correct result but I don't know how to convert it into properties configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regex replacement use `replace{pattern}{regex}{substitution}` pattern. `appender.A1.layout.replace.*` must be removed.

```
appender.A1.type = Console
appender.A1.name = A1
appender.A1.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.A1.layout.pattern = [%d{HH:mm:ss}] %replace{%m}{foo}{bar}%n

# whole line
appender.A1.layout.pattern = %replace{[%d{HH:mm:ss}] %m%n}{foo}{bar}
```

### For More Information

[Log4j2 - Layouts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0-beta7/manual/layouts.html)

> replace{pattern}{regex}{substitution}
>
> Replaces occurrences of 'regex', a regular expression, with its replacement 'substitution' in the string resulting from evaluation of the pattern. For example, "%replace{%msg}{\s}{}" will remove all spaces contained in the event message.
>
> The pattern can be arbitrarily complex and in particular can contain multiple conversion keywords. For instance, "%replace{%logger %msg}{.}{/}" will replace all dots in the logger or the message of the event with a forward slash.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this before, but I think this one is different from replace parameter, it can only replace the string in the event message but not the whole log,so the packge name cannot be replaced. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Hi @MagicRain you can add whole log event as a parameter. I have updated my answer, you can check the `whole line` option. You can free with many alternatives like `%replace{%C %m}{foo}{bar}%n` not an only single element.