# Log4j / Log4j2 replace dot with dot + newline

Tags: replace, log4j, log4j2

I have been trying to replace dots with dots and a new line using log4j / log4j2 but I have been unsuccessful.
How can I replace a dot with a dot and a newline? . -> .\n

My last try was:

```
<PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%replace{[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %p %m}{\.}{\.\n}%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812560/log4j2-how-to-use-replace-parameter-in-log4j2-properties-file) which has been helpful for me to get to this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found out how to do it.
Here is the answer for whoever needs it:

```
<PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%replace{[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %p %m}{\.}{\.&#xD;&#xA;}%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).